# Passing as `const&` lightweight objects

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, micro-optimization

Given the following pet snippet:

```cpp
template<class T1, class T2>
struct my_pair { /* constructors and such */ };

auto f(std::pair<T1, T2> const& p) // (1)
{ return my_pair<T1, T2>(p.first, p.second); }

auto f(std::pair<T1, T2> p) // (2)
{ return my_pair<T1, T2>(p.first, p.second); }
```

If I know that both `T1` and `T2` are lightweight objects whose copy time is negligible (a couple of pointers each for instance), is it better to pass the `std::pair` as copy than as a reference? Because I know that sometimes is better to let the compiler omit copies than force it to deal with references (for example, to optimize copy-chains).

The same question applies to `my_pair`'s constructors, if it's better to let them receive copies than references.

The calling context is unknown but the object generators and the class constructor themselves are all inline functions, so maybe the differences between references and values are not important because the optimizer can see the final target and apply construction at the end of the road (I'm just speculating), so the object generators would be pure zero-overhead abstractions, in which case I think the reference would be better just in case some exceptional pair is bigger than usual.

But if that's not the case (references always or usually have some impact respect to copies, even if everything is inline), then I will go for the copies.

Comment: It’s not just the call you have to worry about, there’s also the indirection, if you pass a pointer it has to do a memory lookup through the address, if you pass a raw value it is usually passed in the registers and is thus directly accessible from inside the CPU. C++ will generally optimize the passing of structures by breaking them up into their individual values and passing those through the calling convention. If both of your values in the pair fit into a register (most if not all primitives should be able to do this) then it will probably be faster to pass by value.

Comment: Of course that being said, we’re talking about a difference measurable in clock cycles. You’re not likely to be able to measure a difference, let alone notice it.

Comment: @vandench Yeah I meant in clock cycles. I know that if objects are lightweight enough they can take even less than a cc.

Comment: @vandench The thing is that maybe the optimizer knows the final target of the reference and omit it(everything from the object generator to the class are inline functions)

Comment: If you are looking for differences in clock cycles I would recommend tagging it `micro-optimization`, that tag is generally more suitable; `optimization` is generally used for large algorithms.

Comment: It is possible for the optimizer to omit references during inlining. It really is up to you. If you can guarantee that the types will always fit it’s fine to do pass-by-value. As I said pass-by-reference isn’t likely to hurt, and during optimization it will likely be optimized away.

Comment: @vandench: No, C++ doesn't "break structures up" for pass/return unless it's inlining the function so there isn't actually any pass/return.  But some good calling conventions (e.g. x86-64 System V) pass object up to 16 bytes in up to 2 registers, if their members are integer/pointer.  Windows x64 puts a strict limit of 8 bytes per arg, passing by reference for any larger object.

Comment: I think if these functions can always inline, it probably doesn't matter which you pick, other than compiler missed-optimization bugs.  If they can't always inline, then it depends (on the target ISA / calling convention, and on the compiler and whether T1/T2 are scalar or themselves larger than a register.)

Comment: @PeterCordes So I see that the key factor here is if the passing values can fit in a register or if they can't. When they can, then it's always better a pass by reference. What about iterators and functors? They are always passed by value for convention by nobody guarantees that they would own less than 16 bytes of state (it's usual that some proxy iterators for instance save a couple of pointers plus a functor that maybe have state), and iterators are objects that are being copied around thousands of times.

Comment: As type is template and usable in generic context, I would use const reference.  as code is probably visible from compiler, it would probably do the best choice internally.

Comment: @Peregring-lk: I think you said that backwards.  When values *can* fit in a register or two, it's usually best to pass by value, not reference.  But again, that only matters when *not* inlining, and you *really* want these functions to inline.  At least with link-time optimization, or just put them in a header because they're pretty trivial and unlikely to need changes.  Same for iterators: you really want simple iterators to inline, not to be opaque objects.

Comment: By the way, there's a lot of typos in your code.

Comment: @PeterCordes The compiler has to break apart a structure to be able to pass it through memory, it could use the stack, but it’ll usually take advantage of the registers: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6YGxwP

Comment: @vandench - I think the point Peter was making that it's not C/C++ that has any semantics around "breaking up structures" but rather it's totally up to the calling convention enshrined in the ABI. For example, Sys V ABI register-passes more types of structures compared to Windows x86-64 calling convention.

Comment: @BeeOnRope This is a question about micro optimization, its inherent nature is about the low level implementation of the language, so it doesn’t matter what the spec says, it matters what implementation has been, is, and will continue to be. x86 hasn’t changed in 40 years, it’s not likely to change in the next 40.

Comment: @vandench - what? x86 changes almost every CPU uarch release by Intel and to a lesser extent, AMD. Anyway, one key to this question is the _ABI_, which is definitely different between x86 and x86-64, and also between platforms. Although I wasn't really saying it matters what the spec said, it does happen to matter what he spec says a bit, because ABIs tie some of their C++ rules to things derived from the spec, like trivially constructible. Of course, if everything gets inlined, it's mostly up to the compiler (spec is still important if ctors/dtors have side effects, etc).

Comment: I guess it also depends on what you mean by "breaking a structure apart". What do you mean by that? It certainly doesn't have to store each member individually or anything like that (and your link doesn't if you turn on optimization).

Comment: @BeeOnRope I was referring the backwards compatibility of x86. Your computer boot into 64 bit mode, it boots into 16 bit real mode, switches to 32 bit protected mode, and finally enables 64 bit long mode. The CPU still has registers A, B, C, D, as well has SP, IP, BP, FLAGS. As for breaking apart structures I was referring to how it is decomposed into a series of bytes along side gigabytes of other bytes, indistinguishable from the rest. Because there isn’t a formal definition of a structure in machine code the compiler is free to pass data through the registers.

Comment: Passing a structure by value causes the compiler to treat each member as just another parameter, thus they are usually passed through the registers because __fastcall, __cdecl, __stdcall, __vectorcall, __thiscall, and the MS x86-64 calling convention all make heavy use of the registers.

Comment: I didn't look up all those calling conventions, but I doubt your claim that they usually pass structures in registers. MS x86-64 only passes structures in registers if they happen to fit in a single register, so the general case and the case of "two pointers" mentioned by the OP won't be passed in registers. Structures are not "decomposed into a sequence of bytes alongside gigabytes of other bytes" - they are passed exactly according to the calling convention. I didn't quite follow of the backwards compatibility of x86 matters here.

Comment: @vandench: no, a `struct { char a,b,c,d; }` is definitely not passed the same as `foo(char a, char b, char c, char d)` in any calling convention, in registers or memory.  https://godbolt.org/z/O19gbO shows an example: struct packed into the low 4 bytes of EDI for x86-64 System V, or in 1 stack slot for 32-bit Windows `__vectorcall`.  vs. 4 separate registers for separate char args.  (Or still 1 stack slot for Windows; apparently `vectorcall` doesn't pack structs into a register even if they fit).  It 100% depends on the calling convention, 0% on the ISA.  That just determines what's possible.

Comment: Even Windows x64 vectorcall passed the small struct by value on the stack, totally unlike x86-64 System V.  @BeeOnRope: that contradicts your claim that Windows x64 passes structs in a reg if they fit in one.  So there's an even bigger difference between what \@vandench was claiming vs. reality.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: The language does extend special permission for copies to be made using trivial copy constructors so as to allow such types to be passed in registers (which is observable because it doesn’t preserve addresses).

Comment: @Chipster Yeah I've seen them now, I didn't know why I miss them yesterday. Thank you.

Comment: There are three ways to determine which variant has better performance. 1. Measure. 2. Measure. 3. Measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outside of the domain of micro-optimization, I would generally pass a `const` reference since you aren't modifying the object and you'd like to avoid the copy. If one day you *do* use a `T1` or `T2` that are expensive to construct, the copy is potentially a big issue: there is no equivalently big footgun with passing a const reference. So I look at passing by value as a choice with very asymmetric tradeoffs and choose by value only when I know the data is small.

As to your specific micro-optimization question it basically depends on whether the call gets fully inlined and your compiler is decent.

### Full Inlining

If either variant of your `f` function gets inlined into the caller, and optimization is enabled, you are likely to get identical or nearly identical code for either variant. I test that [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/v-ClhK) with the `inline_f_ref` and `inline_r_val` calls. They both generate a `pair` from an unknown external function and then call either the by-reference or by-variant of `f`.

Like this for `f_val` (the `f_ref` version only changes the call at the end):

```
template <typename T>
auto inline_f_val() {
    auto pair = get_pair<T>();
    return f_val(pair);
}
```

Here are the results on gcc when `T1` and `T2` are `int`:

```
auto inline_f_ref<int>():
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    std::pair<int, int> get_pair<int>()
        add     rsp, 8
        ret

auto inline_f_val<int>():
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    std::pair<int, int> get_pair<int>()
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

Totally identical. The compiler sees right through the functions and even recognizes that `std::pair` and `mypair` actually have the same layout so all trace of `f` disapears.

Here's a version with `T1` and `T2` being a structure with two pointers, instead:

```
auto inline_f_ref<twop>():
        push    r12
        mov     r12, rdi
        sub     rsp, 32
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    std::pair<twop, twop> get_pair<twop>()
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp]
        mov     QWORD PTR [r12], rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]
        mov     QWORD PTR [r12+8], rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+16]
        mov     QWORD PTR [r12+16], rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+24]
        mov     QWORD PTR [r12+24], rax
        add     rsp, 32
        mov     rax, r12
        pop     r12
        ret
```

That's the "ref" version and again the "val" version is identical. Here the compiler isn't able to optimize all the work: it still does a bunch of work to copy the `std::pair` content to the `mypair` object after creating the pair (there are 4 stores storing a total of 32 bytes, that's 4 pointers). So inlining again let the compiler optimize versions to the same thing.

You can probably find cases where that's not the case, but they are unusual in my experience.

### Without Inlining

Without inlining it's a different story. You mention that all your functions are inline, but that doesn't necessarily mean the compiler will inline them. gcc in particular is more reluctant than average to inline functions (e.g., it didn't inline the *very* short functions in this example at `-O2` without the `inline` keyword).

Without inlining the way parameters are passed and returned is set by the ABI, so the compiler cannot optimize away the differences between the two versions. The `const` reference version amounts to passing a pointer, so regardless of `T1` and `T2` you'll pass a pointer to the `std::pair` object in the first integer register.

Here's the code that leads to when `T1` and `T2` are `int`, in gcc on Linux:

```
auto f_ref<int, int>(std::pair<int, int> const&):
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        ret
```

The pointer the `std::pair` is passed in `rdi` and so the body of the function is a single 8-byte move from that location into `rax`. A `std::pair<int, int>` takes 8 bytes, so the compiler copies the whole thing in one shot. In this case, the return value is passed "by value" in `rax`, so we are done.

This is dependent on both the compiler's ability to optimize and on the ABI. For example, here's the same function compiled by MSVC for a 64-bit Windows target:

```
my_pair<int,int> f_ref<int,int>(std::pair<int,int> const &) PROC ; f_ref<int,int>, COMDAT
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdx]
        mov     r8d, DWORD PTR [rdx+4]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rcx], eax
        mov     rax, rcx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rcx+4], r8d
        ret     0
```

There are two different things happening here. First, the ABI is different. MSVC cannot return `mypair<int,int>` in `rax`. Instead, the caller passes in `rcx` a *pointer* to a location where the callee should save the result. So this function has stores in addition to loads. `rax` is loaded with the location of the saved data. The second thing is that the compiler is too dumb to combine the two adjacent 4-byte loads and stores into 8-byte ones, so there are two loads and two stores.

The second part could be fixed by a better compiler, but the first one is a consequence of the API.

Here's the *by value* version of this function, in gcc on Linux:

```
auto f_val<int, int>(std::pair<int, int>):
        mov     rax, rdi
        ret
```

Still only a single instruction, but this time a single reg-reg move, which is never more expensive than a load, and usually considerably cheaper.

On MSVC, 64-bit Windows:

```
my_pair<int,int> f_val<int,int>(std::pair<int,int>)
        mov     rax, rdx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rcx], edx
        shr     rax, 32                             ; 00000020H
        mov     DWORD PTR [rcx+4], eax
        mov     rax, rcx
        ret     0
```

You still have two stores, because the ABI still forces the value to be returned in memory, but the loads are gone because the MSVC 64-bit API allows arguments *up to 64-bits in size* to be passed in a register.

Then compiler goes and does a really dumb thing: starting with the 64-bits of `std::pair` in `rax`, it writes out the bottom 32 bits, shifts the top 32 bits to the bottom and then writes those out. The world's slowest way to simply write out 64 bits. Still, this code will generally be faster than the by-reference version.

In both of ABIs the by-value function was able to pass its argument in a register. This has its limit, however. Here's the by-reference version of  `f` when `T1` and `T2` are `twop` - a structure containing two pointers, Linux gcc:

```
auto f_ref<twop, twop>(std::pair<twop, twop> const&):
        mov     rax, rdi
        mov     r8, QWORD PTR [rsi]
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsi+8]
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR [rsi+16]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsi+24]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax], r8
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax+8], rdi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax+16], rcx
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax+24], rdx
```

Here's the by-value version:

```
auto f_val<twop, twop>(std::pair<twop, twop>):
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]
        mov     rax, rdi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], rdx
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsp+16]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi+8], rdx
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsp+24]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi+16], rdx
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsp+32]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi+24], rdx
```

Although the loads and stores are ordered differently, both are doing exactly the same thing: 4 loads and 4 stores, copying 32 bytes from input to output. The only real difference is that in the by-value case the object is expected on the stack (hence we copy from `[rsp]`) and in the by-reference case the object is pointed to by the first argument, hence we copy from `[rdi`]<sup>1</sup>.

So there is a smallish window where *non-inlined* by-value functions have an advantage over pass-by-reference: the window where their arguments can be passed in registers. For the Sys V ABI this usually applies to structures up to 16 bytes, and on Windows x86-64 ABI up to 8 bytes. There are other restrictions as well, so not all objects of this size are always passed in registers.

---

<sup>1</sup> You might be saying, hey, `rdi` takes the first argument, not `rsi` - but what happens here is that the return value also has to be passed through memory, so a hidden first argument - a pointer to the destination buffer for the return value - is implicitly used and goes into `rdi`.